# On the Sign of the Definite Integral Involving pdf, cdf, and the hazard rate

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Let $f(.)$ and $F(.)$ denote the PDF and CDF of some continuous probability
distribution (with a support of $S\in (-\infty ,0)$, $S\in (0,\infty )$ or $
S\in (-\infty ,\infty )$) and also let $h(.)$ represent the hazard rate.
\begin{equation*}
h(.)=\frac{f(.)}{1-F(.)}\text{.}
\end{equation*}
I wish to come up with conditions that will ensure the positivity/negativity
of
\begin{equation*}
\int_{z\in S}\left( F(z)\right) ^{n-2}\left( (n-1)\ln F(z)+1\right)
(f(z))^{2}dz\text{,  with }n\geq 2\text{.}
\end{equation*}
under the following assumptions: (1) $f(.)$ and $F(.)$ are differentiable
everywhere and (2) $f(.)$ has a limit of $0$ at $\sup (S)$.

I suspect that the solution has to do with the hazard rate. To this end, I
have reformulated the integration as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\int_{z\in S}\left( F\right) ^{n-2}\left( (n-1)\ln F+1\right) (1-F)(f)hdz
\text{,}
\end{equation*}
and then employed "Integration by Parts" and obtained:
\begin{equation*}
-h\times \frac{\left( (n^{2}-n)F-n^{2}\right) \ln F+F}{n^{2}}F^{n-1}|_{z\in
S}+\int \frac{\left( (n^{2}-n)F-n^{2}\right) \ln F+F}{n^{2}}F^{n-1}dh\text{,}
\end{equation*}
from which I can see that the second part vanishes if $h(.)$ is constant,
which occurs only in the case of the exponential distribution. Furthermore,
in this particular case,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow \sup (S)}\frac{\left( (n^{2}-n)F-n^{2}\right) \ln F+F}{
n^{2}}F^{n-1}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow \inf (S)}\frac{\left( (n^{2}-n)F-n^{2}\right) \ln F+F}{
n^{2}}F^{n-1}=0\text{ for }n\geq 2\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Hence, with constant $h(.)$, I get
\begin{equation*}
\int_{z\in S}\left( F\right) ^{n-2}\left( (n-1)\ln F+1\right) (1-F)(f)hdz=-%
\frac{h(\sup (S))}{n^{2}}\text{,}
\end{equation*}
since I assumed $h(.)$ to be constant. This is where I got stuck. Help is needed.